# How to automatically have temporary session files in session folder delete, php code

Tags: php, session, directory, admin, temporary-files

For my website, I have a sessions folder...I assume from my php code...where every time a user signs in or out, for example, a session file is created.  My problem is, the session files don't delete and remain in my session folder.  So, once the folder hits 20,000 files, my host (GoDaddy) says, no more writing to that folder, and then, no one can sign in or use the members area of the site.

Is there any way to have these temporary session files automatically delete, either by the code or by another script?  I've been manually deleting them every week, to keep the number under 20,000, but this could get crazy if the website continues to grow.

Anyone have an idea about what code I should be looking for or any solution to this issue?  I can leave more detail.  I just don't know where to turn as the developer of the system has gone out of business and I'm stuck for now.

Thank you!

Comment: So your script is writing all of the session data to files in your web folders?  The default PHP session keeps sessions in files but PHP will automatically do house cleaning on old and expired sessions.  Is there a reason you are using sessions this way?

Comment: Yea... typically sessions shouldn't work that way. Maybe the permissions are wrong on the folder, preventing PHP from doing session cleanup? That's the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Hi @greg_diesel thank you.  The system was set up by someone else, and while I'm great with HTML and CSS, I only know basic php...so not really sure why it's set up the way it is.  I could tell you more about what I have.  To answer your question, yes, I believe as you wrote, the php should do the house cleaning on old and expired sessions...so I don't know why it wouldn't be... What is the default php session...a file I should be searching for?

Comment: Hi @JamesSpence ...is this something I should just check in my FTP software?  I've double-checked and the setting looks like all permissions are good to go...

Comment: This post explains how PHP sessions work (normally) http://stackoverflow.com/a/5593377/4179009   and this one shows you some ways of locating where your PHP is putting the session files.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197225/can-you-help-me-locate-php-session-files                My guess is you are storing some other kind of file and those are not being cleaned up.

Comment: @greg_diesel I can see where the files are being saved, but don't know why they're not deleting from the folder...  Here is some code I've come across for example in my "cron" folder, which I read another user finding: echo "Old Sessions Cleared: " . $old_sessions_cleared . "<br />";